# How to stretch/scale the view in VirtualBox fullscreen mode?

Tags: virtualbox, fullscreen

VirtualBox: 5.1.28
Host: Win 10, 1920x1080
Guest: Win XP, 800x600

A simple illustration of what I want:

[image: Fullscreen vs Scaled vs What-I-Want]

In "fullscreen" mode the whole screen is black and there is a small 800x600 viewport in the middle. I want it to behave similarly to normal fullscreen apps, which stretch their viewport ignoring aspect ratio. I don't want Guest OS to think it has a 1920x1080 viewport (as it would if I'd install Guest Additions), **I want it to stretch 800x600 viewport onto 1920x1080 screen**.

The closest to this is Scaled mode: the viewport is scaled ignoring aspect ratio (*which is what I want*), but it has the window title on the top of the screen and taskbar on the bottom (*I don't want neither of these*).

While googling, I've seen [winsupermaximize](https://code.google.com/archive/p/winsupermaximize/downloads) mentioned. It is a program which hides window title similarly to how browsers do when you press F11. But, it is "tested on Windows XP" and has an issue "ignores taskbar", so I guess it's not what I need. The idea was to run it on Win 10 to "super maximize" VirtualBox window. **Maybe there is any other tool to "super maximize" a window?**

---

The app I'm running in Win XP is really fragile and it seems anything can break it. It does not work if I install Guest Additions. Without these it is running well, so I don't want to change anything on Guest side.

Answer (score 0):

There was a guy who posted an answer, but then deleted it. Though he didn't know about VirtualBox, he offered an alternative solution: using VMWare Workstation, because you could achieve the Scaled Fullscreen I wanted.

Isn't exactly the solution I've been looking for, but it might help someone, so here it is.